# JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted. Why it is showing me in the log

Tags: spring-security, jwt

> Utill class

**I am trying to use JWT Authentication in my application. Here is my Utli Class**

```
package com.sushovan.jwt.security.jwtutil;

//import java.security.Signature;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

@Service
public class MyJwtUtil {

    private String secret = "sushovan";

    public <T> T extractClaims(String token, Function<Claims,T> claimResolver) {

        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);

        return claimResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public String extractUserName(String token) {
        return extractClaims(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractexpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaims(token, Claims::getExpiration);

    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractexpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(String username) {
        Map<String,Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, username);
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUserName(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

> Config class

**Here is my config class.**

```
package com.sushovan.jwt.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.sushovan.jwt.security.filter.MyJwtFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private MyJwtFilter myJwtFilter;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());

        return provider;

    }


    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate")
        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(myJwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

> MyFilter class

**Here is my Filter Class**

```
package com.sushovan.jwt.security.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.sushovan.jwt.security.jwtutil.MyJwtUtil;
import com.sushovan.jwt.security.service.CustomUserDetailsservice;

@Component
public class MyJwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    MyJwtUtil myJwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsservice service;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String authorizationToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String token = null;
        String username = null;

        if(authorizationToken != null && authorizationToken.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            token = authorizationToken.substring(7);
            username = myJwtUtil.extractUserName(token);
        }

        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = service.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if(myJwtUtil.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```

> This is the complete log. I want know the reason why it is showing 'JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.' Want to know the root cause of this problem and the solution, how to solve this problem

**Here is my complete log . This is the complete log. I want know the reason why it is showing 'JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.' Want to know the root cause of this problem and the solution, how to solve this problem**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.7.RELEASE)

2020-05-14 01:34:09.162  INFO 7740 --- [           main] c.s.j.security.DevSecurity1Application   : Starting DevSecurity1Application on S-PC with PID 7740 (D:\eclipse-workspace\dev-security-jwt\target\classes started by S in D:\eclipse-workspace\dev-security-jwt)
2020-05-14 01:34:09.214  INFO 7740 --- [           main] c.s.j.security.DevSecurity1Application   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-14 01:34:14.639  INFO 7740 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-14 01:34:15.058  INFO 7740 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 392ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-14 01:34:19.799  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2020-05-14 01:34:19.943  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-14 01:34:19.944  INFO 7740 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
2020-05-14 01:34:20.789  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-14 01:34:20.790  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 11291 ms
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-05-14 01:34:21.518  INFO 7740 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-14 01:34:21.558  WARN 7740 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2020-05-14 01:34:24.934  INFO 7740 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-14 01:34:25.652  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-14 01:34:26.564  INFO 7740 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-05-14 01:34:28.995  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-14 01:34:29.874  INFO 7740 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-05-14 01:34:34.489  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-14 01:34:34.512  INFO 7740 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-14 01:34:35.815  WARN 7740 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-05-14 01:34:36.842  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2ba9f986, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3d512652, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@23ea8830, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@49038f97, com.sushovan.jwt.security.filter.MyJwtFilter@718989fa, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3b96f8b0, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5dfc2a4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4aa3fc9a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@44da7eb3, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2b9aeedb, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4d0e1a9a]
2020-05-14 01:34:37.382  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-14 01:34:38.753  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-14 01:34:38.757  INFO 7740 --- [           main] c.s.j.security.DevSecurity1Application   : Started DevSecurity1Application in 33.709 seconds (JVM running for 37.509)
2020-05-14 01:34:54.392  INFO 7740 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-14 01:34:54.394  INFO 7740 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-14 01:34:54.469  INFO 7740 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 75 ms
2020-05-14 01:34:55.200 ERROR 7740 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:354) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.sushovan.jwt.security.jwtutil.MyJwtUtil.extractAllClaims(MyJwtUtil.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sushovan.jwt.security.jwtutil.MyJwtUtil.extractClaims(MyJwtUtil.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sushovan.jwt.security.jwtutil.MyJwtUtil.extractUserName(MyJwtUtil.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sushovan.jwt.security.filter.MyJwtFilter.doFilterInternal(MyJwtFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
```

Comment: If anything more needed for clarification please write a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
.setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("you signing key value"))
```

Please try this hope it works.

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help. Please find helpful information for that here [answer] and [tour].